# Line isn't drawing at the top corner

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm attempting to draw two lines -- I understand that 0 is suppose to start at the corner, but for me it seems off. I know it isn't the code that's wrong and I've tried doing negative numbers for the x-coordinate, but the line disappears.

Those who wanted the size of my frames:

```
2014-03-29 21:12:28.294 touchScreenClockTest[5178:70b] height      = 568.000000
2014-03-29 21:12:28.295 touchScreenClockTest[5178:70b] width       = 320.000000
```

What I want it to look like:

[image: What I want]

What it looks like:

[image: Actual image]

```
// Draw the top line
CGContextRef drawTopLine = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(drawTopLine, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

// Draw them with a 2.0 stroke width so they are a bit more visible.
CGContextSetLineWidth(drawTopLine, 1.5);

CGContextMoveToPoint(drawTopLine, 0,5); //start at this point

CGContextAddLineToPoint(drawTopLine, 300, 5); //draw to this point

// and now draw the Path!
CGContextStrokePath(drawTopLine);

// Draw the bottom line
CGContextRef drawBotLine = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(drawBotLine, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

// Draw them with a 2.0 stroke width so they are a bit more visible.
CGContextSetLineWidth(drawBotLine, 1.5);

CGContextMoveToPoint(drawBotLine, 0, 30); //start at this point

CGContextAddLineToPoint(drawBotLine, 300, 30); //draw to this point

// and now draw the Path!
CGContextStrokePath(drawBotLine);
```

Also one more question. I wanted to know how to put the navigation button on my own. I have the image of the navigation, but I didn't know what I would need to call to place the image UIView? (since I don't have a storyboard)

Comment: Where did you put the above drawing code?  Can you try putting an `NSLog` in to check the frame property of the view you are using the drawing code in?

Comment: moreover you should use bounds while setting line width. Else you will have issues in landscape mode

Comment: What do you mean NSLog? Like the debugging. Could you give me an example. I put this in my clock.m file and I have app delegate and view controller.

Comment: I didn't let this go landscape mode. This app is only portrait only

Comment: I would put a bounty on this if I had enough points for ya

Comment: Fixed the problem I was alloc the clock within the view and the clock was a different dimension